# ImportError: No module named pandas. Pandas installed

Tags: python, macos, pandas, anaconda

I am pretty new to programming and am having issues importing pandas to my program. Hoping someone could point me in the right direction to fix this. I am running OSX

**regresson.py**

```
import pandas as pd
import Quandl

df = Quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
print df.head
```

and am getting the error:

```
import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named panda
```

I have anaconda on my system.

Pandas 0.17.1

Numpy 1.11.1

Scipy 0.18.0

Pytz 2016.6.1

Comment: Try `help('modules')` and see if `pandas` shows up.

Comment: No mudule named panda or pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure to activate your conda environment

in your terminal-

```
conda create -n environment_name quandl pandas
cd path_to_env 
activate environment_name 
(environment_name)conda list (make sure u have the right packages)
(environment_name) your_program.py
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 # if using pip 
 pip install pandas
 # if using anaconda
 conda install pandas
 # after this step use this
 conda update -all
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Python imports, and the language itself, is case sensitive. This means that after you fix the pandas installation, you'll also need

```
import quandl
```

and not

```
import Quandl
```

On another note, it's worth noting that we usually call `df.head()`, not `df.head`. This way, when working on a Jupyter notebook, as an example, the formatting is nicer. Also you can specify the number of first rows you want to see, such as `df.head(10)`.